# How to specify python version when running impala-shell inside airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I wonder if this is supported or not but there are many use cases that needs to run impala-shell, what I tried and saw (failed) is impala-shell is still on python 2, though p2 is specified in impala-shell.py, for some unknown reason Airflow doesn't switch to p2 from p3, and hence failed for codes written in p2 in impala-shell.py, one example below:

```
task1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test_impala-shell',
    bash_command="impala-shell -i hadoop01 -B -q 'select * from sr.sr2010' -o sr2010.csv '--output_delimiter=|'",
    dag=dag)
```

error:

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

So the questions here are:

1. why the specified python version of 2 in impala-shell.py is NOT used as the interpreter lanaguage?
2. how can customize a dag or task in airflow to run a different python version?

Thank you. Any share/enlighten/clue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The BashOperator in Airflow doesn't know anything about python versions, or impala - it just runs commands at a shell.

The likely cause of differences from running these commands yourself would be environment variables, espeically PATH.